# c# - More efficient serialization for packets

Tags: c#, sockets, serialization

I'm creating a program which has to send data between a client and server efficiently. To organize packets clearly, I'm using serialization. However, when I serialize these packets the data is unnecessarily large. I'll explain what I'm doing so that you can understand what I need.

My packet classes work like this. I have a Packet object:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

[Serializable]
public class Packet
{
    public static byte[] Serialize(Object o)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        bf.Serialize(ms, o);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }

    public static Object Deserialize(byte[] bt)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

        ms.Write(bt, 0, bt.Length);
        ms.Position = 0;

        object obj = bf.Deserialize(ms);

        ms.Close();

        return obj;
    }
}
```

I can then create other classes that inherit from the Packet class, here's an example:

```
using System;

[Serializable]
public class PacketUserInfo : Packet
{
    public string Name;
    public int Age;
}
```

Then, it's very simple to put this into a byte array and send it (Of course the above packet is merely an example). However, the size of the resulting array is at least 10 times larger than it would be if I was to use a BinaryWriter and manually write the information.

Why is the serialized data so large? Is there any way to decrease it while still keeping everything organized with packets as their own classes?

Note: I'm only intending to serialize simple properties like this, nothing fancy.

Comment: While I cannot give you exact reasons for such a behaviour, I'd like to recommend a serialization library, which I have co-authored, Migrant - https://github.com/antmicro/Migrant . It allows to serialize your classes with small overhead in resulting data and virtually no boilerplate code. In fact for simple cases it does not require any code. Also it provides features such as complex graphs of objects with cycles etc.

Comment: I'll have a look at it... If it looks like it won't take much work to switch to it, I'll try it. Thanks.

Comment: `BinaryFormatter` is not a good choice for machine to machine searization, if the two machines have different DLL versions of the core .NET DLLs (say one machine has not run it's windows updates yet when a hotfix to .NET came out) your data will fail to desearalize. (I don't even recommend it for saving to disk for the same machine, the only place it should be used without worrying about desearalizeation problems is for IPC communication on the same machine)

Comment: I see, so how else can I send my data while keeping it in these tidy classes?

Comment: As I said, for most cases Migrant does not require any additional code.
Please bear in mind that Migrant is optimized for large portions of data and further optimizations for small classes are yet to come. For example, if you'd just serialize one portion of such a small Packet, it would probably take a bit more space than a binary formatter. If you'd need any help with it, just write to the email provided on github, we'll answer ASAP.

Comment: @Jordan by using a 3rd party searializer like the two already suggested in answers and comments (personally I like protobuf) or any of the 100's of one ones out there.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were advising me to avoid such serialization altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where you say *"Why is the serialized data [...] larger than it would be if I was to use a BinaryWriter and manually write the information"*, with *information* you mean *property values*. The serializer you use however, serializes not  only the *data*, but also some information about the *class*. You can see this by viewing the serialized data in a text editor.

> Is there any way to decrease it while still keeping everything organized with packets as their own classes?

Use more specialized serialization, like [protobuf](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) or the library [suggested by @Piotr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21224003/more-efficient-serialization-for-packets#comment31967050_21224003).

Also I think your serialization code should not reside in the `Packet` base class, but rather in a separate class, like `PacketEncoder`.